# How to click on the element as per the given HTML through Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I want to send instagram shipment with mobile imitation. but I need to click on a button for the new shipment. I tried everything about button click but I did not manage it.

```
public static void HoverMouseOverClicks(IWebElement element)
    {
        Actions action = new Actions(insta);
        action.MoveToElement(element);
        IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)insta;
        executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);arguments[0].click();", element);
    }
```

code click-through code you've seen above

```
HoverMouseOverClicks(insta.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/nav[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/span")));
```

I try this and I still can not get the result.

```
 insta.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/nav[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/span")).Click();
```

This code sometimes clicks and sometimes does not click.

The XPath path never changes.

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="q02Nz _0TPg" role="menuitem"><span class="glyphsSpriteNew_post__outline__24__grey_9 Szr5J">Yeni Gönderi</span> <span class="glyphsSpriteNew_post__outline__24__grey_9 Szr5J">Yeni Gönderi</span></div>
```

what should I do?

Comment: Please add relevant html

Comment: <div class="q02Nz _0TPg" role="menuitem"><span class="glyphsSpriteNew_post__outline__24__grey_9 Szr5J">Yeni Gönderi</span>
<span class="glyphsSpriteNew_post__outline__24__grey_9 Szr5J">Yeni Gönderi</span></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML you have shared to click on the element with text as **Yeni Gönderi** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@role='menuitem']//span[contains(@class, 'glyphsSpriteNew_post__') and contains(.,'Yeni Gönderi')]"))).Click();
```

Comment: @Appiah Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.